# How do I resolve a ssh connection closed by remote host due to inactivity?

Tags: ssh

I'm currently trying to ssh to a colo, after 1 to 2 minutes of inactivity, I get:

```
superuser@thecolo:~$ Connection to 10.123.45.67 closed by remote host.
Connection to 10.123.45.67 closed.
mylocalmac:~ superuser$
```

As long as I am typing something in the ssh terminal, the connection is kept.  As soon as 1 to 2 min of inactivity has happened, I will get the above message.  The machine I'm trying to connect to is a Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 64 bit server edition.  It's not a physical server but a guest VMware.  I'm sshing from a mac terminal.

Please don't confuse this question with similar ones on this site with the keyword `ssh_exchange_identification` in it, it's unrelated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add the following to your $HOME/.ssh/config and all your ssh connections will send a TCPKeepAlive every 30 seconds:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 30
```

Comment: unable to find config file on server

Comment: You can create the file in your home directory if it does not exist

Comment: How to create ssh config file, if it's not there yet, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133300/how-to-access-and-modify-a-ssh-file-on-mac

Comment: I noticed it only happened when I'm on 4G as opposed to a stable cable internet connection. Also had to set the interval to 15 seconds, 30 didn't make it for me.

Comment: If you are using Putty. Change the keepalive setting in Putty. Increase that value to 15 or 30 in the Putty connection settings.

Answer (score 11):

If you are connecting from a Linux computer you can use some options directly from the command line

> TCPKeepAlive: This uses the KEEPALIVE option of the TCP/IP protocol to keep a connection alive after a specified interval of inactivity. On most systems, this means 2 hours. So, with the TCPKeepAlive option passed to SSH, the SSH client will send an encrypted packet to the SSH server, keeping your TCP connection up and running.

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes user@some.host.com
```

> ServerAliveInterval: This sets a timeout interval in seconds, which is specified by you, from which if no packets are sent from the SSH client to the SSH server, SSH will send an encrypted request to the server for a TCP response. To make that request every 30 seconds:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 user@some.host.com
```

[Source](http://pthree.org/2008/04/16/keeping-your-ssh-connection-alive/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to "keepalive"

Depending on your client, this maybe trivial or just easy - it shouldn't be any harder!

For example, in *putty* it's on the connection option (set keepalive to a non-zero value)

Comment: Where do I set the keepalive?  On the server or from my mac?  Where should I set that value and what's the recommended value?

Comment: Keepalive will be on the client... in your case, your Mac.  There will be an option somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the suggested solution but couldn't fix the problem. What worked for me was disabling ssh multiplexing. I changed `ControlMaster auto` to `ControlMaster no` in `~/.ssh/config` file.

Adding this answer in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and I solved it as follows:

**Allow SSH Access To A User**

To allow SSH access for a particular user, for example `superuser`, **edit in your server `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file**:

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

**Add or modify the following line:**

`AllowUsers superuser`

Save the file (Ctrl+O)

**Restart ssh, in Debian for example:**
`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Now, you should be able to connect!

Comment: -1. The OP is able to connect. The question is about being disconnected *later*. I don't think this answer addresses the question. The answer probably solves *some* problem, but not the problem in the question.